# Failed to instantiate Angular module when injecting $http service in module.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have this web app that is using `PHP` for the backend and `AngularJS` on the frontend. It was all running fine until today when I got this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module preguntasExamen due to:
> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http

This is the module config:

```
app.config(function($http){
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $http,defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        return $.param(data);
    }
})
```

I need that in order to populate the `$_POST` superglobal when sending form data to the server. I had no problem with this until today. I need to know what is causing this problem.

Thanks in advance!

I didn't try anything because I can't find any other posts that resolve this issue nor do I know what is causing it because the application was running fine and I didn't touch this part of the code for days.